# c++ array of type class

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I have just started learning c++. I have a question in an assignment that reads: Consider the following class declaration with a main() function. There are two errors in the main() function. Name them and explain how to fix them.

```
//Question Three Start
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Restaurant
{
public:
    Restaurant();
    int getTables();
    int getTempStaff();
    int getPermStaff();
    string getShifts();
private:
    string Menu;
    int Tables;
    int TempStaff;
    int PermStaff;
    string Shifts[3];
};

int main()
{
    Restaurant mimmos;
    //.........(additional code)
    string menu = mimmos.Menu;
    //.........(additional code)
    //get information about shift 3
    cout << "Shift info:" << mimmos[2].getShifts() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I know that the first issue is that the member variable Menu is private, but i am not sure how to fix the issue with the mimmos[2].getShifts() and how to use an accessor/mutator function. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Restaurant mimmos;` - not an array, `string menu = mimmos.Menu;`  - not accessible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first you have correctly identified is caused by access to a private member. The fix? A public member function which returns the menu:

```
string getMenu();
```

The second is an invalid attempt to treat 'mimmos' as an array when infact it is a single instance. Since the comment above it indicates it is an attempt to get information about the third shift. You have two choices: change the "getShifts" function to take an index parameter:

```
string getShift(size_t n) {
    return Shifts[n];
}
```

and then you would obtain information about the 3rd shift by writing:

```
cout << "Shift info: " << mimmos.getShift(2) << std::endl;
```

Or change getShifts() to return an array pointer:

```
string* getShifts();
```

then you would write:

```
cout << "Shift info: " << mimmos.getShifts()[2] << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are tree problems with this code:

```
string menu = mimmos.Menu;
```

Menu is declared private in Restaurant class.

```
Restaurant mimmos;
//get information about shift 3
cout << "Shift info:" << mimmos[2].getShifts() << endl;
```

"mimmos" is single object and not an array. And in this case square brackets operator "[]" is used to access an array member.

Also according to comment above that line: "get information about shift 3"

You want to access the shift number 3 but the return type of "getShifts" function is single string object. So even if you move square brackets to front of the function :

```
cout << "Shift info:" << mimmos.getShifts()[2] << endl;
```

You will get a single char (3rd char of the string).

[std::string::operator[]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator[]/)

Answer (score -1):

Because you are only creating a single object of `Restaurant` class, not an `array` so you cannot use with `index` there.

You should use as follows

```
cout << "Shift info:" << mimmos.getShifts() << endl;
```

Also to access `private` variable expose a `public` method which will return the `Menu` field.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Read the comment directly above the getShifts line.